# second level document update in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update a second level document that is current_data array object ,the following information i followed but i am not able to update through node mongoose update but i can excute query in mongo shell.
The Schema is :

```
canvas : {
    current_data : [{
        product_id : { type : String, required : true },
        item_id : { type : String, required : true },
        image_id : { type : String, required : true },
        created_by : { type : String, required : true },
        controller : { type : String },
        dimension: { height : { type : Number, required : true }, width : { type : Number, required : true } },
        position : { x : { type : Number, required : true }, y : { type : Number, required : true } },
        angle : { type : Number, required : true },
        depth : { type : Number, required : true },
        created_at : { type : Date, required: true, default: Date.now() },
        updated_at : { type : Date },
        deleted_at : { type : Boolean, required : true, default : 0 }
    }]
}
```

Query :

I converted my product._id to ObjectId then i am firing the query

```
model.findOneAndUpdate( { _id : chatId , 'canvas.current_data' :{ $elemMatch:{_id : product._id } } },{ $set:{'canvas.current_data.$': product } },{safe:true,new:true}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error result is ',err);
        return cb(false, [err.errors],null);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you also post the code section where you create the model variable and assign something to it?